# Linq Order by when column name is dynamic and pass as a string to a function

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a Linq (Entity Framework) Query as

```
function getData(string col_to_sort , bool IsAscending , int pageNo , int pageSize)
{
  context.table_name.Skip(pageNo*pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToArray();
}
```

What i want is that if i pass the name of the column as a parameter to the function
and the order it will sort my query too.

Since my column name will be a string so we might need to convert it to ObjectQuery.

How can i achieve this?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx):

```
string direction = IsAscending ? " ASC" : " DESC";
context.table_name.OrderBy(col_to_sort + direction).Skip(pageNo*pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToArray();
```

Comment: it works for me but i need to use it like "OrderBy("it.id desc")"? do we always need to use "it" what is this it

Comment: uh, not sure... it doesn't seem to be needed in the examples on Scott's blog

Comment: An update after years: there are several new libs on github via nuget. one of them is https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic

Comment: github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic  is deprecated now

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dynamic Linq, then the accepted answer will work.

But If you don't want to add an extra library (Dynamic Linq), then you can pick my first approach. I will explain both the approaches where you have or don't have Dynamic Linq. You can select based on your preferences and choice.

**First Approach: When you don't have Dynamic Linq:**

If you are using `using System.Linq;` instead of `using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`, then you can use this approach:

- `orderBy` is the string and Student is the T (The Entity, in which we want to search).

Create a Utility class, something like this: (you can anytime covert to extension method If you wish.)

```
public static class LinqUtility 
{
        public static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
            var propAsObject = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(propAsObject, parameter);
        }
}
```

And you can use like this:

```
public async Task<IList<Student>> GetStudents(long groupId, string orderBy, Filter filter)
{
 return await _context.Students.Where(x => x.StudentGroupId == groupId)
           .OrderByDescending(LinqUtility.ToLambda<Student>(orderBy))
           .Skip(filter.Skip)
           .Take(filter.Take)
           .ToListAsync();
}
```

**Second Approach: When you have Dynamic Linq:**

- The Dynamic LINQ library exposes a set of extension methods on IQueryable corresponding to the standard LINQ methods at Queryable, and which accept strings in a special syntax instead of expression trees.
- You need to include the Library separately. Include `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`. **The Author of this Library is not Microsoft.**. As such no harm in using it.
- So, this Library, provides you a method, that accepts the string.
- You can pass comma separated values as well in string, this can be achieved by above code as well, but some changes would be required.
- In the same example, just pass orderBy:

```
public async Task<IList<Student>> GetStudents(long groupId, string orderBy, Filter filter)
{
 return await _context.Students.Where(x => x.StudentGroupId == groupId)
           .OrderBy(orderBy)
           .Skip(filter.Skip)
           .Take(filter.Take)
           .ToListAsync();
}
```