# how to use a dynamic variable in orderby clause

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

am a newbie in linq.. am stuck with one scenario. ie,

i have to sort the search results based on user input.

user inputs are Last Name, First Name and  Title. for input 3 drop downs are there and i have to sort result based on the values selected.

i tried

```
order = Request["orders"].Split(',');

                var param = order[0];
                var p1 = typeof(Test).GetProperty(param);
                param = order[1];
                var p2 = typeof(Test).GetProperty(param);
                param = order[2];
                var p3 = typeof(Test).GetProperty(param);


model.Test = (from tests in  model.Test
                   select tests).
            OrderBy(x => p1.GetValue(x, null)).
            ThenBy(x => p2.GetValue(x, null)).
            ThenBy(x => p3.GetValue(x, null));
```

but it doesn't works.

i want qry like this

```
from tests in  model.Test
select tests).OrderBy(x => x.lastname).
ThenBy(x => x.firstname).ThenBy(x => x.Title);

order[0]== lastname but how can i use it in the place of OrderBy(x => x.order[0])..?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq Order by when column name is dynamic and pass as a string to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398453/linq-order-by-when-column-name-is-dynamic-and-pass-as-a-string-to-a-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved my case as follows
// list of columns to be used for sorting

```
 List<string>order = Request["orders"].Split(',').ToList();
```

//map the column string  to property

```
var mapp = new Dictionary<string, Func<Test, string>>
            {
                {"FirstName", x => x.FirstName},
                {"LastName", x => x.LastName},
                {"SimpleTitle", x => x.SimpleTitle}

            };
```

//user inputted order

```
var paras = new List<Func<Test, string>>();
            foreach (var para in order)
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(para))
                paras.Add(mapp[para]);
            }

//sorting
            model.Test= model.Test.OrderBy(paras[0]).ThenBy(paras[1]).ThenBy(paras[2]);
```

Thanks all,

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are looking for dynamic linq query than you can try out [Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

which allow to do like this

[image]

it means you can dynamically pass string propertyname to short you collection in orderby function

You can also read about : [Dynamic query with Linq](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2011/04/dynamic-query-with-linq.html)

Comment: when i try 
 string a = order[0];

var reslt =(from tests in  model.TestFlatDatas 
select tests).OrderBy(a);

OrderBy shows the error as "The type arguements for method IOrderedEnumerable<Tsourse>System.Linq.OrderBy<TSourse,TKey>(this Ienenumerable<TSourse>,Func<TSource,Tkey>)' Cannot be inferred from the usage. Try Specifying the arguments explicitly.

Comment: @AnishKarunakaran- have you reference dynamic linq library by downloading it from msdn or from the scott gu article link..if not than download library and than refrece in your project than try the example given over here ..

Comment: am sorry that i ddn't find such one.. i added Nuget system.Linq.Dynamic.. but no difference.
Could u please specify the download link.

Comment: @AnishKarunakaran - here is download link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb894665.aspx

Comment: @AnishKarunakaran - just include dynamic libraray cs file in your project thats it...

Answer (score 0):

You can compose the expression (any [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx)) manually from pieces and then append it to the previous part of query. You can find more info, with example in "[Sorting in IQueryable using string as column name](http://blog.cincura.net/229310-sorting-in-iqueryable-using-string-as-column-name/)".