# Pagination with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, pagination

We have orderby clause in LINQ to SQL just like below but do we have anything for pagination?

```
from trans in DB.transactions 
orderby trans.column descending 
select trans;
```

Or we have to do it manually (sort of) like following query?

```
(from trans in DB.transactions 
orderby trans.column descending 
select trans).Skip(noOfRecords).Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: Yes. You have to do it by helping `Skip` and `Take` methods.

Comment: use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72469192/4393351

Answer (score 0):

As I know you must use `.Skip` and `.Take`, but you can write an extension for `IQueryable` to easy your work:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Paging<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageLength)
    {
        return source.Skip(pageNumber * pageLength).Take(pageLength);
    }
}

var source = (from trans in DB.transactions 
orderby "cancellation_reason_id" descending 
select trans);

source = source.Paging(0, 10); // Get first page with 10 item
```

Comment: Should be `pageNumber * pageLength` and not `&`

Comment: @Mats391 Thank's Edited

Comment: Thanks @Feriloo but I didn't asked how to use Skip and Take best but just the possibility of any other work around (may be something in linq to SQL).

Comment: check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72469192/4393351